# Creating file with FAT file-system

Tags: c, fat, lpc

I have this problem : I'm using FAT FS and LPC4088 and after I divided physical drive with f_fdisk, and mounting two partitions apparently without problems ( I get FR_OK as result value for every used fs function),  then I create a file, I write on it and then close it, always with a FR_OK result value. Then I check the file and I get a FR_NO_FILE error
The code look like this

```
static FILINFO fno;
static  FIL fdst;
static DWORD plist[] = {50, 50, 0, 0};
FRESULT rc;
char error;
static BYTE work[512];

error = 0;

rc = f_fdisk(0, plist, work);    /* Divide physical drive 0 */
/* rc=FR_OK */

rc = f_mount(&FS1, "0:", 1);      /* Register work area to the logical drive 0 */  
if (rc!=FR_OK) 
{
    rc = f_mkfs("0:", 0, 0);
}

rc = f_mount(&FS2, "1:", 1);      /* Register a work area to the logical drive 1 */
if (rc!=FR_OK) 
{
    rc = f_mkfs("1:", 0, 0);
}

rc = f_open(&fdst, "0:myfile.bin", FA_WRITE | FA_CREATE_ALWAYS);
if (rc!=FR_OK) error =1;    /* rc=FR_OK */

rc = f_write(&fdst,"abcde",5,&nwritten);
if (rc!=FR_OK) error =2;  /* rc=FR_OK */

rc = f_close(&fdst);
if (rc!=FR_OK) error =2;   /* rc=FR_OK */

rc = f_stat("0:myfile.bin", &fno);
if (rc!=FR_OK) error =4;   /*rc = FR_NO_FILE*/
```

Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

Comment: If you were doing this at the command prompt,  It would still not work.  Nothing can be read/written (successfully) to a file system until the file system has been formatted

Comment: Is it normal to not stop your prog on error ? you set error but you don't use `return` or `goto` to break the run

Comment: Since you're continuing after errors, as Ôrel pointed out, the value of `error` contains a value according to the last error you encounter. You're probably getting errors before then and the value in `error` is overwritten by later errors.

Comment: you might want to check the supplied documentation at: <https://developer.mbed.org/users/embeddedartists/code/app_qspi_format/file/03417cea6ccc/main.cpp>  for a very simple example.  Including the detail that the file system needs to be formatted

Comment: If you really want to plough on (following @RossRidge) it's better to `OR` unique bit value errors rather than over write them, as in `error |= 2;`

Comment: @user3629249  doesn't `_mkfs` format a file system?

Comment: you might want to read this documentation: <https://developer.mbed.org/users/embeddedartists/notebook/lpc4088-quickstart-board---software-information/> which (amongst other things) discusses why not to use a 'fat' file system

Comment: the posted code, after having a call to f_mount() fail, calls f_mkfs()   Shouldn't that be only call f_mkfs() when the mount is successful?  And why continue the program when a failure occurs?

Comment: @WeatherVane, thanks for pointing that detail out.   That makes some of my comments less than fully useful. :-(

Comment: I should have written `f_mkfs` typo error.